# Initialize a json object to a variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

```
(function() {
   var app = angular.module('myApp', ['chartjs-directive']);

   app.controller('myController', function($scope,$http){
       var chart_data = {};

       $http.get('js/chart_data.json').success(function(data){
          chart_data = data;          
       });  

       $scope.myChart = {"data": chart_data, "options": {} };
   });

})();
```

If chart_data is directly assigned to key value pairs its working fine...

How to initialize `chart_data` variable inside `$http` service. The above syntax is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

$http returns a promise, so you need to set the scope variable inside the callback:

```
$http.get('js/chart_data.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.myChart = {"data": data, "options": {} };
});
```

Comment: I had tried ur solution.. the error is `Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`

Comment: Where do you get that error? In the callback - or at a later stage? Can you debug in Chrome?

Comment: debugged in chrome..  error is from angularjs library

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the line in the callback. What is the value of data there?

Answer (score 0):

It should be like:-

```
(function() {
   var app = angular.module('myApp', ['chartjs-directive']);

   app.controller('myController', function($scope,$http){
       $scope.chart_data = {};

       $http.get('js/chart_data.json').success(function(data){
          $scope.chart_data = data;     
      $scope.myChart = {"data": $scope.chart_data, "options": {} };     
       });  


   });

})();
```

Comment: I still get error.. `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: If i directly initialize the chart_data I get the proper output.. If i get it using `http` and initialize i am getting errors... the json file is correct..

Comment: ok the problem is you need '$scope.chart_data' and it is not getting data while $http call is in progress in that case you can do two things first place  $scope.myChart = {"data": $scope.chart_data, "options": {} }; inside http or you can use $watch

Comment: if i log `$scope.chart_data`  inside $http service the object is correct but outside $http i.e in controller its empty

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work. We faced this issue many times.

We should take data after $http request. And no need of taking chart_data here

```
(function() {
   var app = angular.module('myApp', ['chartjs-directive']);

   app.controller('myController', function($scope,$http){
       $http.get('js/chart_data.json').success(function(data){
           $scope.myChart = {"data": data, "options": {} };
       });  

   });

})();
```

We can use $scope.myChart.data in html as myChart.data and in any part of controller

Comment: Ur suggestion is not working.. By the way i am using custom directive.. I dont want to display data in html directly

Comment: Ok. Please share your custom directive code also..we will discuss further

Answer (score -1):

`var chart_data = {};` this way you can initialize it as a an empty JSON obj.

Comment: `chart_data` is getting initialized to `data` inside `$http` but in controller if i log it its an empty oblect

Comment: put a watch on `chart_data` `$scope.$watch($scope.chart_data,function(oldVal,newVal){console.log(newVal);})`  and observe the logs